# Loading XML files to sheets of one Excel workbook using C#

Tags: c#, xml, excel

I have an XML file that I am trying to load to into an existing workbook in Excel. I realize that I can simply open the file and it will load into Excel easily. I am trying to get it to load to a specific sheet within my already open workbook. What would be the best practice for this? I have the path of the XML file which is in a string, but I am lost on where to go from there.

Comment: How are you automating Excel?

Comment: I am not sure if I answering this correctly so I will just step through it, this is a Ribbon that is loading a path from a sheet. So you would type a string indicating the directory, you click a button I have added to the ribbon and it reads that path as a string, I just want to take that directory (which will be a XML) file and load it to another sheet.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably look into the Excel COM automation API.  This allows you to take data that you have in memory, or in an XML file in your case, and programmatically place it into whatever cells you want in the workbook.  It's a lot more work, but it gives you a lot more control.

From C#, you would want to look at the [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel%28v=office.11%29.aspx) dlls, if you choose to go this route.  Hopefully someone else will come along and give you an easier answer, but that's the best that I can think of right now.

Comment: How about loading the xml into a dataset then loading it into the active sheet?